# setTitle method not working in Child Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parent-child

I'm new to Android development. Normally in any activity class, I just simply use `setTitle("My title")` at any place will do then the window title will change dynamically.

However, when I try using this method in child activity, it won't have any effect. When I try use Toast, Menu option it also no effect at all.

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean under "child Activity"?

Comment: You need to add some code for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: You need to add more information for your question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032823/android-activitygroups-child-activity-settitle-not-working