# Android setTitle in the tab ActivityGroup

Tags: android

My application is Tab using ActivityGroup.I have done title of each activity using `getParent().getParent().setTitle("New Tilte");`.

My Problem is :

I have 2 tab.

Sale have 3 child .

```
 RouteActivity - Title--Route
 Retailer      - Title--Retailer
 OrderActivity - Title--Order
```

Inquiry have 2 child ..

```
 StockActity -- Title Stock Inq
 PriceActivity-- Title Price Inq
```

Currently i am in inquiry tab's `StockActity`when I click the `Sale` Tab,It show `Retailer`(last open activity) activity.But it didn't show title as `Retailer` but show as `Stock Inq`.

I.e) When I navigate/switch tab, it want to show selected activity's title name.

Currently it showed previous tab's selected activity title name. It didn't change.

I did using this `getParent().getParent().setTitle("New Tilte");`.

[Android ActivityGroup's child activity setTitle not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032823/android-activitygroups-child-activity-settitle-not-working)

Please help me out from this bug.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your code:

```
getParent().getParent().setTitle("New Tilte");
```

to `onResume()` of every `Activity`.